# Audio - MP3 Streaming

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to create a system for mp3 streaming live and I'm having trouble. When the code finishes the first track, the second track plays. This is my code using jQuery (minimum), AJAX, and JavaScript:

```
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple">
<button id="openNewSessionButton" disabled>Open New Room</button><br />
<script>
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection('stream');
connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    oneway: true
};

// connect to signaling gateway
connection.connect();

// open new session
$("#openNewSessionButton").click(function() {
    connection.open();
});

$("#file").change(function() {
var fileA = this.files[0];
var fileB = this.files[1];
readFile3(fileA);


function readFile3(file){
    var file1 = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var context = new AudioContext(),
        buffer;

    var playAudioFile = function (buffer) {
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0); // Play sound immediatel
        var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        source.connect(destination);

                        connection.attachStreams.push(destination.stream);
                        connection.dontAttachStream = true;
                        $("#openNewSessionButton").removeAttr('disabled');



            var current2 = source.buffer.duration;
            var n = Math.floor(current2);
            var b = n * 1000;

            var timer = setTimeout(function(e) {

            readFile3(fileB); //THIS LINE ? IS CORRECT ?

            }, b);
    };

    var loadAudioFile = (function (url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('get', file1, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


        request.onload = function () {
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(incomingBuffer) {

                        playAudioFile(incomingBuffer);

                     }
                );
        };

        request.send();

    }());
});
</script>
```

seems it is not possible to do that with this new API, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the AudioContext very well, but if you have a look at

```
 http://html5test.com
```

you will see the poor mp3 support of the browsers. If your browser support mp3 you can use the Audio tag and with some nice javascripts (search for "html audio player javascript controlls") it will do your job.